# $n^{1/n}\to 1$ implies $(p(n))^{1/n}\to 1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I had an exercise where I had to prove that $n^{1/n}\to 1$ when $n\to \infty$. But I was wondering if I could in a nice way directly deduce that $(p(n))^{1/n}\to 1$ when $n\to \infty$ for any polynomial in n with positive coefficients.

Comment: in fact you only need to show for a monomial $an^k$ since the term of higher degree is dominant (just factor it out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

As a polynomial of degree $d$ is $O(n^d)$, is suffices to prove the claim for $cn^d$.

Now with $m:=\dfrac nd$,

$$(cn^d)^{1/n}=c^{1/n}n^{d/n}=c^{1/dm}d^{1/m}m^{1/m}\to1\cdot1\cdot1.$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\large (p(n))^{1/n}=e^{\frac{\log(p(n))}n}$$

then we reduces to prove that

$$\frac{\log(p(n))}n \to 0 \iff \frac{k\log n+\log a_1+\log\left(1+\frac{a_2n^{k-1}+\ldots+a_{k+1}}{a_1n^k}\right)}n \to 0$$

or as an alternative we have that eventually

$$\left(a_1n^k\right)^\frac1n\le (p(n))^{1/n} \le \left((k+1)a_1n^k\right)^\frac1n$$

then refer to squeeze theorem.